# AWS IOT - RegisterThing fails -- InvalidCertificateOwnershipToken

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, esp32, aws-iot, provisioning

This is a real challenge.   I have been successful in everything up to this point in Fleet provisioning on an embedded device.  I have subscribed and published to topics and received new certificates and keys.  But, when I take the certificateOwnershipToken that has been given to me and I try to trigger a DeviceRegistration, I get:

{"statusCode":400,"errorCode":"InvalidCertificateOwnershipToken","errorMessage":"Certificate ownership token cannot be empty."}

My token is 466 characters long and I send it with 2 other items in this string:

{"certificateOwnershipToken":"eyF1ZXJzaW9uIjoiMjAxOTEwMjMiLCJjaXBoZXIiOiJBaURqMUdYMjBiVTUwQTFsTUV4eEJaM3ZXREU1dXZSSURoTy80cGpLS1o1VkVHdlZHQm81THNaS1VydG0zcTdoZGtVR0l1cmJZS0dLVkx2dTZNL2ViT2pkVFdIeDEwU3o3aFZPeExERkxWVlJ4OUIvL2RzcXRIeVp1WVo2RXZoU1k0L0txQ0doZ1lyRklwZGlLK05pUlNHMXlLQXJUSGJXSkNlVUxHcHRPWHJtdHJaNWJMUyt1MHFUcjNJVnlVLzNpcGZVVm1PanpmL3NCYzdSNkNyVGJPZ05Nc2xmOXdHSVRWM0tPUjd1aFFSbnZySnY0S1ZtU2hYc2REODI4K1crRE1xYnRYZGUxSXlJU29XZTVTSHh6NVh2aFF3OGl3V09FSzBwbG15Zi82dUgyeERoNjB1WS9lMD0ifQ==","parameters":{"SerialNumber":"82B910","CertificateId":"175b43a3d605f22d30821c4a920a6231978e5d846d3f2e7a15d2375d2fd5098c"}}

My templates looks right, my policy looks correct.   The role which is attached to my template seem to cover my needs.   I just don't know how AWS is failing without more information.

Does anyone have ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: NEW INFO:   I just disabled that template -- and the error message did not change.   ALSO-- I have the Lambda provision-hook disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem.   In C/C++ aws iot sdk -- there is a data structure where you must specify the payload string and a few other things.  One of those data elements is the length of the payload and I forgot to set that length before sending my payload to the $aws/provisioning-templates//provision/json   topic.   Once I set that length, then the submission worked and the template was acted upon and the thing was created